# Evaluating indefinite integral with any hint or solution

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I evaluate this indefinite integral.

$$
\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^3+x+1}}
$$

any hit would be appreciated.

Comment: It does seem to have a nice looking [closed-form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2F(x*sqrt(x%5E3%2Bx%2B1))). Where is this from?

Comment: Some sort of elliptic integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "reduces" to an incomplete elliptic integral.
Somewhat more generally,

$$ \int \dfrac{dx}{x \sqrt{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}} = {\frac {\pm 2\,i}{a \sqrt {a-c}}{\it EllipticPi} \left( {\frac {\sqrt {a-x}}{\sqrt {a-b}}},{\frac {a-b}{a}},{\frac {\sqrt {a-b}}{\sqrt {a-c}}}
 \right) }$$

(using Maple's notation).  In your case you want to take $a,b,c$ to be the three roots of $x^3+x+1$ (one real root approximately $-0.682327803828019$, two complex roots approximately $0.341163901914009693 \pm 1.16154139999725192\,i$).